# MvvmCross (v3): Is that wrong to (try to) use behaviours and storyboards in a multi-platform application?

Tags: c#, windows-8, mvvmcross

i would like to know what is considered the best practice (or how other people would have solved this problem) in this scenario.

I'm trying to create a simple game with MvvmCross that will (hopefully) run on different platforms. Actually i just have previous experiences of Windows Phone development only, and i'm now "making a step further" by trying to work with WinRT apps (next step...Android!).

Even if is a simple game, i need to create some animations here and there to make the things a little bit more interestings/smoother.

On WP7 i was used to create Storyboards (using Blend) and use Behaviours to trigger animations in response to value changes, correct answers and so on, all avoiding code-behind tricks.
I simplistically thought that i could easily do the same things also on the other platforms, one way or another, but i think that i have to reconsider a lot of details =>
(Today i've learned that WinRT doesn't supports behaviours and eventTriggers)

For completeness i'll write two examples of problematic scenarios:

1) I have some elements that are hidden (transparents), and i want them to show up only after the user clicks on a button. ( So the "flow" will be something like: View -> VM -> PropertyChanged -> Trigger(?))

2) I need to fire a different animation based on the result of the execution of a method (that will check the user answer, so i'll have a "winner" or a "loser" animation).

So my questions are:

1) How can i solve those issues in WinRT apps? Is there a best-practice? I was looking to this project (http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/), but i don't know if it will fits well with MvvmCross.

2) Can i sleep easy knowing that i will find a (hopefully simple) way to reproduce a similar behaviour (and animations) on Android and iOS?

I hope that i've successfully explained myself.
Thanks to everyone =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i don't know if it will fits well with MvvmCross.

For each and every single platform, the challenges of showing animations and the challenges of hooking events to ViewModel properties and commands are platform-specific problems.

These things are all View-specific problems and so you should be able to solve them in each View layer (in the individual UI projects).

> How can i solve those issues in WinRT apps? Is there a best-practice?

For WinRT at least one person has used behaviors from nuget - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/behaviors-for-windows-8-winrt-store.html

> reproduce a similar behaviour on Android and iOS?

In my experience, binding to Android and iOS UI events is easier than hooking into XAML ones - in general you don't need `EventToCommand` type adapters because Mvx binding can work directly with events.

> (and animations)

Animations are down to each platform/UI. Both Android and iOS have established ways of doing animations.

- For Android, I recommend watching http://dotnetmobilepodcast.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-animations.html
- For iOS, I recommend watching http://dotnetmobilepodcast.blogspot.com/2012/09/delighting-your-users-with-coreanimation.html

iOS animations are particularly easy to do and particularly beautiful - you will need some C# code to do these, but that code will be much shorter than XAML.

---

With all these questions, I would recommend you push on and try... you should be able to implement them without changing your shared core - and you should be able overcome the challenges one platform at a time.

Good luck with your easy/hard sleep problems.

Comment: I really, really, really want to thank you once more. I'll try to resolve those issues and, once successfull, i'll try to blog them somewhere (actually, i don't have a blog =>). And, thanks for the excellents N+1 videos series, i've just viewed the n=5 =)